# SendRedirect inside GWT RPC doesnt work with jsp

Tags: jsp, gwt, servlets, redirect, rpc

I have GWT RPC service and i am doing something like this inside my RemoteServiceServlet :

`this.getThreadLocalResponse().sendRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8888/myapp/errorServlet");`

this works , hovewer when i am trying to redirect to jsp page (http://127.0.0.1:8888/ErrorPage.jsp)  nothing happens. (no errors)
and my url is 100% correct.

I have tried to use also

`getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(URL).forward(request,response);`

but result was the same.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT-rpc reponse cannot be HTML - it has to be a proper RPC response.  I think you will get an error which is being ignored in your GWT code -  check the onFailure method of your AsyncCallback or the GWT log if you are using dev mode or the javascript console if you are trying the production mode.

Comment: you're right i get onFailure. So is there any way to redirect with POST from server side in GWT ?

Comment: No, the client side expects a java object to be returned. What do you want to achieve with the redirect?

Comment: I want to redirect to my error page when exception is thrown inside gwt rpc service. ( My problem is that i am not really sure if onFailure method will catch all exceptions (not only HTTP)) ? Thanks for help

Comment: RPC is an AJAX call - there is no way of changing the browser content. You will have to add logic in the onFailure method - I think it will get called always.

Comment: ok thanks, so how can i make redirect with post from client -side?